# Enable PUT and DELETE requests in ASP.NET MVC app for Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, windows-10

I have ASP.NET MVC website (4.5). I try to run this application under **Visual Studio 2015** and get the "Page not found" exception on `PUT` and `DELETE` requests.

How to enable these requests?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this for some solution, in solution root it will be `.vs\config` folder and `applicationhost.config` file. In this file you need to add `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs for `ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0` module, like that

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

However I think there is should be nicer way to do that via UI, but I don't have Win 10 installed so can't check now. Will be good if some one else tell how.

Comment: Thanks. But it will be nice to know how to do this for all solutions, not only for one project. Also I check Handler mappings section in IIS and looks like there is no 'ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0' so how to set this from UI?